# jQuery Modal Dialogs and MVC3 Partial Views

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a jquery modal dialog that displays a partial view.  The partial view contains a form which posts back to see if the entered value is valid.  What I want is the error message that I return in the controller to be displayed on the partial view without refreshing the page.  How do I do this ajaxically?

Partial View:

```
    @model SimpleSalon.Data.Models.GiftCard

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddGiftCard", "Sales", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="addGiftCardForm" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Correct the errors below:")

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Card Number</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CardNumber)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.InitialBalance)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddGiftCard(GiftCard model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //if it's valid in the db continue on
            //else ModelState.AddModelError("", "card number not valid.")
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddGiftCard", "Sales", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "container" }, new { @class="addGiftCardForm" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Notice that I have used `UpdateTargetId = "container"` in the AjaxOptions. This means that the partial result returned by the `AddGiftCard` action will be injected into a DOM element with `id="container"`. So make sure you put such element to wrap the partial in the jQuery dialog.

Also for this to work make sure you have referenced the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the Ajax methods were no longer recommended, and that using jquery $.ajax was preferred

Comment: So I've got the ajax postback working correctly now.  How should my controller code look when adding a modelstate error?  Do I return a PartialViewResult?